# gitattributes gets ignored on checkout

Tags: git

We recently switched from svn to git in my company, therefore the overall know-how is still pretty low.

We decided to set core.autocrlf=true on every machine and to use ".gitattributes" files for "finetuning" purposes.

My Main Focus is an Integration-Project with apache-camel to transforms files from "a" to "b". As a lot of endpoints are different i need to ensure encoding, line endings etc. In my Tests with apache camel i take a static File from my test-resources, transform it and compare the output with another static file (basically the expected output) in my test-resources.

This used to work perfectly until we introduced "core.autocrlf=true". Since then the tests seem to complete successfully on jenkins, but when i run them locally a lot of them fail. (I freshly cloned the Repository after "core.autocrlf=true" introduction). 
I searched for 1 of the expected output-files. If i check the line endings on my machine (win 10) they are "crlf". If i check the line endings of the file from the Repository they are "lf". This conversion was to be expected with core.autocrlf=true.

However i tried adding a ".gitattributes" file. With these two Specifications:

```
* text=auto
*.xml binary
```

I just used "*.xml" as for easier testing if it works. Basically what i need is, that all of my files under test-resources should be ignored. But with the above ".gitattributes" file, i still get the testfile with crlf on my machine, even if i freshly clone the whole repo and do "git checkout branchname". It is the same behavior if i do

```
*.xml text eol=lf
```

or

```
*.xml -text" etc.
```

From my Understanding what i read so far is that if i specify a path or a filetype as "binary" git should not do any conversion at all if i do git checkout, git commit or git whatever.

Did i misunderstand something, or am i just doing something wrong, or is git not doing as it should?

Comment: You said that you cloned your repository freshly after setting `core.autocrlf`.  Did you do so again after updating your `.gitattributes`?

Comment: yes. I propably did so about 20 times until now, while i was testing around with gitattributes

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I would expect this to work with the .gitattributes you specified, and in my tests it appears that it does.  I guess it could be a git version issue, or you might want to review your test procedure to make sure there wasn't just an error in the setup

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will propably try it another time then. And if it doesnt work i let another one of my team try the very same thing. Alltough that will propably need to wait for at least 1 more workday.
I will give Feedback after i tried it out another time. Maybe i missed to report something here, or maybe i missed something while i was testing around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this, but i propably need to write down first how the setup is and how i did this initially.

So we have a master branch as the default (basically the branch that contains the "live-code" or the code to be live soon), and the develop branch. We create feature and bugfix branches from develop and merge them back when the bug is fixed or the feature is finished.

So what i did initially is: on bitbucket i created a branch from develop (lets just call it branchX). Locally i opened the git-bash console:

```
git pull
git checkout branchX
```

i then created the gitattributes file with the Specifications in my first post. After that i commited and pushed to the remote repo. I completely deleted my local repo and did:

```
git clone remoteRepoUrl
cd repoName
git checkout branchX
```

After that the files still showed as crlf instead of lf.

After the answers here i tried it another time i did go the same way until the last part.
instead of cloning and checking out into my branch i did

```
git clone --branch branchX remoteRepoUrl
```

This clones the repo but directly checks out the wanted branch. My gitattributes Specifications seem to work now.

However the strange thing is, if i do

```
git checkout master
```

now i still get the lf lineendings which is fine, but actually should not be, as the master branch does not have a .gitattributes file and therefore should just use the autocrlf config.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem, but `git clone --branch branchX` did the trick!